# How to switch web driver to an unknown frame?

Tags: selenium, web, driver, frame

I'm writing a java tool which will create selenium scripts for end users. In case of frame switching, I cannot depend on end user to figure out the frame info. User can provide a locator value, but my tool needs to be able to figure out which frame it belongs to (it's hierarchy structure) and switch to the one before taking next action.

Is there any way I get my Selenium Web Driver to get that frame?

PS: I could hard code the workflow with frames known and do the switching.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I can think of is, check for presence of provided locator/element on current context (frame), if it throws NoSuchElementException exception, get all the available frames on the page - `driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"))` and in a loop try to switch to available frames based on WebElement`driver.switchTo().frame(<element>)`, now again check for the presence of provided locator/element. Once you found provided locator/element, break the loop and continue with further execution.

Comment: Excessive nesting/control switching here but yes, does look one way if there isn't anything else.